# image size with jquery without pre-defined in tag then pass to CSS

Tags: jquery, css, image, size

Is there a way to find out the width and height of the follow image with Jquery?

```
<div id="imgBox"><img id="imgID" src="images/koala.gif" /></div>
```

Then pass it into CSS?

```
<style type="text/css">
   #imgBox, #imgBox img { width:imageWidth; height:imageHeight }
</style>
```

I'm guessing...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       var imageWidth = $("#imgBox").width();
       var imgHeight = $("#imgID").height();        
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you set the CSS dynamically?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // make sure img is loaded:
   $("#imgID").load(function() {
       var $this = $(this);

         // Set dimensions of box  using dimensions of img
       $("#imgBox").css("width",  $this.width());      
       $("#imgBox").css("height", $this.height());
   });       
});
```

You can ofcourse add to the values of `$this.width()` and `$this.height()` when you set the `css` for `#imgBox` if you need to for aesthetic reasons... let's say if you have a background image in `#imgBox` you want to show the edges of.

Comment: You guys are awesome! I learned a new tool today. CSS in Jquery is gonna be PB&J to me. Thanks dudes.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
$(function() {
    var imgSrc = $('#imgId').attr('src');        
    var image = new Image();
    var width, height;       
    image.onload = function() {
        width = image.width;
        height = image.height;
    };
    image.src = imgSrc;        

});
```

You could then write the CSS with JavaScript.

```
$('<style />', {
    html: '#imgBox, #imgBox img { width:' + width + 'px; height:' + height + 'px }',
    type: 'text/css'
}).appendTo('head');
```

*But*, why do you need to do this?

Comment: I think you're forgetting that images may not be cached ;)

Comment: @Nick I'm not aware that is a problem! Are you saying this code will fail if the user has turned off their cache?

Comment: Images take time to load, in your code above unless it's already cached, the values will be 0 :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way , but can you tell why do you want to overwrite css.

```
        var $imgId = $('#imgId');
        var h = $imgId.height();
        var w = $imgId.width();
```

do all your math here

```
 $imgId.css('height', yourcalculatedheight);
 $imgId.css('width', yourcalculatedweight);
```

you can parse the dom and change it dynimically instead of going and changing the css which might be good approach

Comment: let me know what excatly you want to do for that image , i can post the code.

Comment: 4 spaces before a line formats as code. `ctr-k` does this on a selection.